# what is a difference in the width of the spinning bar?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, continuum-mechanics

The bar with length l, density r, diametr d, Young's modulus E, Poisson's ratio mu, is spinning around the cross-section, what is the change in the width of this bar?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question...

Answer (score 0):

The answer i arrived at, assuming angular velocity=w, Poisson's ratio=v, area of crossection=A; is:-
Change in diameter = -dvr$w^{2}$$l^{2}$/2E 
Additionally, the change in the length of the rod = r$w^{2}$$l^{3}$/2E. 
Getting to the answer:- 
[image: The diagram]

The increase in length of the *dx* element in the figure is given by( we can get it from the formula E=FL/A(*dL*):-
 *dy* = *dm* $w^{2}$l x/A 
Putting, 
 *dm* = rA *dx* ,  
we get,
 *dy* = r$w^{2}$l x *dx*/E 
 
Integrating it we get, 
 change in length of rod= y =  r$w^{2}$$l^{3}$/2E. 
If we put *dy* in the equation of change in diameter due to axial stretching(as given on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_ratio#Width_change) ), 
change in diameter in *dx* element = *du* = -dv *dy*/l  
hence, 
*du* = -dvr$w^{2}$ x *dx*/E  
Integrating we get, 
 change in diameter = -dvr$w^{2}$ $l^{2}$/2E